# Xiaomi Mi A1 SurfaceView upside down

Tags: android, surfaceview, android-camera2, xiaomi

I'm stuck on this. **Xiaomi Mi A1**, *sometimes* is presenting the SurfaceView I use for camera preview upside down. This is happening when I switch to a new CaptureSession.

Documentation report to not explicitly close the previous session, but I suspect that the delay in closing the old one, is messing things up. It's like if the SurfaceView needs a sort of refresh, because if I build a request of configuration update and give it to the capture session, the SurfaceView is fixed and correctly rotated and the *onClosed* callback of the capture session is immediately called.

My app is fixed in landscape. Anyone faced a similar problem? I really need help on this. Many thanks in advance.